# How do I remove HTML tags from page display in Webview?

Tags: android, html, webview, rss, plaintext

I am a noob to android development and i am trying to display rss feeds in a webview.  They display as plain text and show the html tags along with the feed details. I've tried switching user agents to no avail. Is it possible to use a regex to display the feed in a clean/proper html format? Any help is greatly appreciated.

How i load my webview

```
try{                
            newsfeed.loadUrl("http://feeds.feedburner.com/GoldMoneyGoldResearch");              
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

is something like this possible? How do i achieve this effect?

```
try{                
            newsfeed.loadUrl("http://feeds.feedburner.com/GoldMoneyGoldResearch").replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");                
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

EDIT

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_darn);

    newsfeed = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    try{                
        String content = newsfeed.loadUrl("http://feeds.feedburner.com/GoldMoneyGoldResearch").toString();//<--trying to parse rss feed to string
        newsfeed.loadData("<html>" + content + "</html>", "text/html", "utf-8");            
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have parsed a RSS feed before and what I did was load it into a webview like this, after i have parsed it. Have you parsed it into listview or other?

```
newsfeed.loadData("<html>" + CurrentPodcastContent + "</html>", "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: no, i havent.  i use .loadurl during onCreate?  Could i do loadurl().tostring = content and then do your suggestion?

Comment: OK, have a look at some rss tutorials, your technique is simpy displaying a website, http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/creating-a-simple-rss-application-in-android/ or http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/newsdroid-rss-reader, as RSS is a XML file you can also look at XML parsing tutorials